# Left of the Combobox must be clicked for it to work

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, activex

The Excel Comboboxes (on an excel sheet) work only if you click on the left side of the arrow.  If you click on the arrow of the combobox nothing happens.
Issue does not occur on all laptops.

the combo boxes are activeX and run VBA code when changed.

Any idea what is causing this and how it can be solved ?

Cheers!

Oliver.

Comment: Clicking on the arrow should show all available options = all items in the ComboBox. If this is empty then this means that there are no items to select from. Yet, if you append to the change event of the ComboBox some code it might still seem as if the ComboBox works (populating the ComboBox upon change). That's all I can think of without any additional hint.

Comment: Close all the opened excel workbooks in your laptop and delete the Excel8.0 folder in temp folder. Now try opening your macro workbook.

Comment: @Prabukrishna, Where can I find the temp folder? Cheers!

Comment: Temp folder Path-->                                                      C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Temp                                  Replace the [UserName] with your username.